# Background Image Animation

Tags: css

does anybody have a advice how to animate the oversized background image in such way: It should smoothly move from the left to the right, from top downwards, from right to left and then up again. I hope it´s understandable with the sketch below.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried some HTML/CSS/Javascript for it yet? If yes, provide us your fiddle link with your code.

Comment: Have you read [using CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations)?

Comment: I tried a motion in one direction http://jsfiddle.net/XXUyj/1/ But this doesnt work well because it appears a white margin on the bottom while it move. http://superhaufen.de/motion.jpg

Comment: At Stack Overflow, it is our sole purpose to help you as much as possible. However, this site is for help with trying to fix your code, not giving you code. If you want people to help you, then it would be appreciated to have some evidence of research

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use animations.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XXUyj/4/

HTML:

```
<div id="bg"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#bg {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 60;
    background-image: url('http://superhaufen.de/earth.jpg');
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-name: slide;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    background-size: 200% auto;
}
@keyframes slide {
    0% {background-position: 0 0;}
    25% {background-position: 100% 0;}
    50% {background-position: 100% 100%;}
    75% {background-position: 0 100%;}
    100% {background-position: 0 0;}
}
```

Just make sure to add in all the vendor-prefixes when you are done playing with it (@-moz-keyframes, @-ms-keyframes, @-webkit-keyframes, etc)

Here is an updates jsfiddle with the vendor prefixes (http://jsfiddle.net/XXUyj/5/).  I didn't include microsoft, because all versions of IE that support animations support them without vendor prefixes, and I didn't include opera, because well, I normally don't.  It doesn't have enough marketshare to warrant the extra CSS size, and they are going webkit next version anyhow.